# Transcendental number that can be writen without "symbols"

Tags: linear-algebra, transcendental-numbers

I know that : $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental numbers, yet I was wondering is there transcendental numbers that are written without any "symbols" ?

I mean we use the symbol $\pi$ to denote the real number : $3.14...$ and $e$ the real number : $2.71$

Comment: See [Numbers proven to be transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental).

Comment: Thank you, it seems that :$2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental

Comment: But "it is written is symbols".

Comment: I would prefer "the fixed point of the cosine function".

Comment: The issue is that the transcendentals are uncountable many and we can "write" only at most a denumerable "number" of numbers... But we can always add a new specific symbol (or name) for a number that has been proved to be transcendental (and thus that has been in some way uniquely identified).

Comment: Not sure this would be considered 'without symbols' either, but the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) is specified entirely by means of its decimal representation.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, ... are symbols, too.

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily need $e$ and $\pi$ to denote those numbers, they just come up enough that it's convenient to denote them as such.  For example, we could also write $$e = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$ or $$e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}.$$

Comment: True, but this is not a closed form

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about closed forms

Answer (score 0):

It seems that : $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational